# Audio for spectrogram or audio for text

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010, delphi-xe

I need some api or routine in Delphi (any version) to convert audio to text or convert audio to spectrogram.
Sorry for any translation errors.

Comment: Take a look at https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg-delphi/?source=directory - it has Delphi source code for ffmpeg - and ffmpeg can be used to make spectrograms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509906/ffmpeg-can-i-draw-an-audio-channel-as-an-image#answers-header

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.